# How do I detect mobile clients on my web server?

Tags: mobile, request, http-headers, webserver

When http request comes to my server, how do I detect if it is from iphone, android, or other devices?

Comment: Are you using that using javascript or server side code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can grab the User Agent. That tells what browser type it is (iphone, chrome, ie, anything)

To help you:

http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Answer (score 8):

You need to check the header of the HTTP request. You can find both the OS and the browser being used in the "User-Agent" field.

If you are using javascript then use the `navigator` object

```
navigator.userAgent
```

If you are using php then you can access the HTTP header

```
$userAgent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
```

Comment: Do note that this is easily faked.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes of course. But I don't see any issues arising from that since the users would prob want the best experience and layout that fits the actual client being used. So they don't really have any interest in doing that.

Comment: @ceejayoz Also I don't think the OP can do anything to prevent that on his end...

Comment: Agreed. Just worth noting, as I've seen people try to restrict access in this manner and be surprised that it won't work for determined users.

Comment: In the case of iPhone can I also get ESN, IME ID of the phone using JavaScript?

Comment: @user736659 I don't think so.

Comment: @JJPA true, [offender](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1554910/kirankumar) is now suspended and the illegal answers deleted.

Comment: @JJPA not my doing, just reporting it to prevent the author here from getting confused when the link you posted does not give him the answer you meant to show..

Answer (score 0):

As [@dave-delong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong) states in his [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5981804/1480391) you can use the [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) HTTP header.

But User-Agent can be quite hard to parse.

I recommend you to use **third party libraries** for **parsing User-Agent** and detecting mobile.

## On Node.js

Apparently OP uses Node.js and then can use [mobiledetect.js](https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js) ([demo](http://zeno.github.io/mobile-detect-demo/)).

> Detect the device by comparing patterns against a given User-Agent string (phone, tablet, desktop, mobile grade, os, versions).

```js
const MobileDetect = require('mobile-detect');

const md = new MobileDetect(req.headers['user-agent']);

console.log(md.mobile());   // 'Sony'
console.log(md.phone());    // 'Sony'
console.log(md.tablet());   // null
```

## On PHP

On a PHP server [mobiledetect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) ([demo](http://demo.mobiledetect.net/)).

> Mobile_Detect is a lightweight PHP class for detecting mobile devices (including tablets). It uses the User-Agent string combined with specific HTTP headers to detect the mobile environment.

Comment: When I test, the user-agent field looks identical on iOS when using Brave, Chrome, or Safari.